# Error of Install R in linux/Red hat(error while loading shared libraries: libRblas.so)

Tags: r, linux

I installed R on redhat using the following commands:
`yum install R`

when I run the R, I get an error like so:
`/usr/lib64/R/bin/exec/R: error while loading shared libraries: libRblas.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Finally I run the following commands:`ldd /usr/lib64/R/lib/libR.so`
I get the information:

```
        libRblas.so => not found
        libgfortran.so.3 => /lib64/libgfortran.so.3 (0x00007ffb64852000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007ffb64550000)
        libquadmath.so.0 => /lib64/libquadmath.so.0 (0x00007ffb64314000)
        libreadline.so.6 => /lib64/libreadline.so.6 (0x00007ffb640ce000)
        libtre.so.5 => /lib64/libtre.so.5 (0x00007ffb63ebe000)
        libpcre2-8.so.0 => /lib64/libpcre2-8.so.0 (0x00007ffb63c47000)
        libpcre.so.1 => /lib64/libpcre.so.1 (0x00007ffb639e5000)
        liblzma.so.5 => /lib64/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007ffb637bf000)
        libbz2.so.1 => /lib64/libbz2.so.1 (0x00007ffb635af000)
        libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007ffb63399000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007ffb63191000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007ffb62f8d000)
        libicuuc.so.50 => /lib64/libicuuc.so.50 (0x00007ffb62c14000)
        libicui18n.so.50 => /lib64/libicui18n.so.50 (0x00007ffb62815000)
        libgomp.so.1 => /lib64/libgomp.so.1 (0x00007ffb625ef000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007ffb623d9000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007ffb621bd000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007ffb61df0000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007ffb651f2000)
        libtinfo.so.5 => /lib64/libtinfo.so.5 (0x00007ffb61bc6000)
        libicudata.so.50 => /lib64/libicudata.so.50 (0x00007ffb605f3000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007ffb602ec000)
```

I'am not good at linux, so I don't know how to deal with it.
How can I start the R successfully? Thanks.

Comment: Hi leewan, I'm not familiar with RedHat at all, but it seems to me that `libRblas.so` should be part of `openblas`, maybe try to install that first with `yum install openblas-devel`, see [here](https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS/wiki/Precompiled-installation-packages), or maybe try to search on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/search?q=rhel+%5Br%5D).

Comment: Hi Petr, thanks for your help. Finally, I run ```mv /usr/lib64/R/lib/libRrefblas.so /usr/lib64/R/lib/libRblas.so``` and let R run successfully!

Comment: Great! I'm quite new here, but I think you can write it as answer here and accept it yourself so that your solution (even on your own question) can help other visitors with similar problem. :-)

Comment: OK, thank you for your advice~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I run
`mv /usr/lib64/R/lib/libRrefblas.so /usr/lib64/R/lib/libRblas.so` and let R run successfully!